# Django Save Wiping out New One to One Relationship?

Tags: python, django, object, save

I'm trying to save a one to one relationship in Django, but after I save the Address object, it deletes the relationship on the object that I'm trying to create a relationship to.

In this case, I'm trying to create a relationship between a 'Person' object that already exists in my database and an 'Address' object that I'm creating. I can assign the Person's address attribute to the new address, and it shows up before the save. However, after the save of the person, the Person's address object disappears. I checked to make sure I have the right MySQL permissions in the settings file, and I can do everything i need to do to save a new object. In the database, there is a new address entry, but there is no address associated with the person entry in the Person table. What am I doing wrong?

```
if person.address == None:
    person.address = managerModels.Addresses()
person.address.zipCode = newAttributeValue # set up zip code
print("Address pre-save {}".format(person.address))
person.address.save()
print("Address post-address save: {}".format(person.address))
person.save()
print("Address post person-save: {} ".format(person.address))
```

The output on the terminal is

```
Address pre-save None None None None 94536
Address post-address save: None None None None 94536
Address post person-save: None
```

Here are the way that the models are declared in the models.py file.

```
class Person(models.Model):

    userId = models.OneToOneField( settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name = "User account", on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null = True)
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    phone = models.CharField("Phone Number", max_length=12)
    address = models.OneToOneField(Addresses, verbose_name = "Address", on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True)
    tutorType = models.CharField("Category", max_length=12)
    gender = models.CharField("Gender", max_length=6)
    subjects = models.CharField("Subjects", max_length = 256)
    email = models.CharField("Email", max_length = 45, blank = True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default = True)


    class Meta:
        ordering = ('userId', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'phone','tutorType', 'gender', 'subjects')
        db_table = 'Persons'

    def __str__(self):
        return "\n{} {}\nPhone: {}\nAddress:{}\ntutorType: {}\nGender: {}\nsubjects: {}\nemail: {}\nactive {}".format(self.firstName,self.lastName, self.phone, self.address, self.tutorType, self.gender, self.subjects, self.email, self.active)


class Addresses(models.Model):
    address1 = models.CharField("Address Line 1", max_length=128, null=True)
    address2 = models.CharField("Address Line 2", max_length=128, null=True)
    city = models.CharField("City", max_length=64, null=True)
    state = models.CharField("State", max_length=64, null = True)
    zipCode = models.CharField("Zip Code", max_length=5, null = True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('address1', 'address2', 'city', 'state','zipCode')
        db_table = 'Addresses'
    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {} {} {} {}".format(self.address1, self.address2, self.city, self.state, self.zipCode)
```

The relationship between Person and address is one to one. Is there anything obviously wrong that I'm doing? I've narrowed this issue down to this exact few lines of code and I am still stuck. Any advice?

Edit: I have updated the code so that I'm only working with an instance of the person address, but the save on the person is wiping out the address data. still don't know what's wrong.

Comment: What are all those other Nones? Show the full model including the str methods and any signals.

Comment: @DanielRoseman done!

Answer (score 1):

You should save the `Address` object before you add it to the `Person` instance. Like this:

```
address = managerModels.Addresses() # create a new address
address.zipCode = newAttributeValue # set up zip code
address.save()

person.address = address
person.save()
```

Comment: that is essentially what I'm doing now, but the address still gets wiped out when I save the person instance back to the database. This is a MySQL database, if that helps at all.